# Why does extra alignement tab error occur in this table?

Tags: tables

First of all let me start out by saying that I'm very new to anything regarding tables in Latex. That being said, here is my problem:

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
  a & b & c & d & \hline
\end{tabular}
```

So why does the error `extra alignement tab has been ....` occur? And how do I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the final `&` should be `\\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tabular definition, you define four columns.
Columns are *separated* by `&`:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4
\end{tabular}
```

Thus, only between columns you need to put `&` - and nowhere else (in particular, do not end the last column with `&`).

Rows are separated by the newline `\\`:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 \\
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 \\
\end{tabular}
```

(You may end the last row with `\\`, but that's optional and the final "empty" row is ignored)

Note that \hline needs to start at a new row, thus:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 \\
\hline % no \\ here, \hline is a complete row on its own
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Therefore, as David points out, change your last `&` to `\\`